# What does $index mean in Angular and how can we use it? (examples for clarity)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to some of the terminology in Angular, I have seen @Max Lynch define Ng-repeat as Ng-for, as in it works like a for loop. What does $index mean in basic terms, can you give an example?

I have read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat I'm asking for clarity.

Comment: This is explained in the `ng-repeat` documentation **and includes examples**. Try reading the manual before asking. Basic research is expected here before asking questions

Comment: See, [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: [how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: have updated the question, thank you for your input @ charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$index is a special variable scoped to the ng-repeat that you're in.  Let's say you have five items and you do something like:

```
<li ng-repeat='item in items'>{{ $index }}</li>
```

You'll get five li elements like:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: okay for this basic example, could you say the "for item in items", where items is defined in JSON format?

Comment: where does `for` come from? That's not part of ng-repeat syntax

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, going fast.  Corrected now.

Comment: @Fabian in that case items is defined somewhere as a javascript arraylike object (could be an array, could be something iterable).  One way would be in the relevant controller to declare `$scope.items = [1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: So working on this concept would the output be:

0
1
2

For the amount of item in items where index starts at 0?

Comment: @Fabian, yes, Javascript uses 0-indexed arrays.

Answer (score 2):

In angualr, **`$index`** is a way to show **`which iteration of a loop`** you’re in.

Say for example, if you are familiar with for loop ,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{

}
```

In the above , it is going to loop for 3 times and **`i`** indicates the **`current iteration.`**

In angular,

If you take a sample,

```
 <li  ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
 </li>
```

where index refers to the current iteration which starts with 0,  Look at the following sample in order to understand in detail,

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('ngRepeat', []).controller('repeatController', function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [
    {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script  src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app='ngRepeat'>
  <div ng-controller="repeatController">
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    </li>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```